# if-statement not working with curly brackets

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Excerpt code:

```
    var x=0, direction=1;

    function fun_1() 
    {
        var dom_obj=document.getElementById("dir");
        x+=direction;
        if(x>=300 || x<=-300)
            direction=-direction;
            dom_obj.style.left=x;
            window.setTimeout("fun_1();",5);
    };
```

This works fine. However, if I add curly brackets in the `if statement`, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[Working](http://plnkr.co/edit/VdWvrSN9g7loRnP9EXj2?p=preview), without `{}`

[Not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/BgTWdXdDAIeN7SbJYNt3?p=preview), with `{}`

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use curly brackets it like writing:

```
if(x>=300 || x<=-300) {
    direction=-direction;
}
dom_obj.style.left=x;
window.setTimeout("fun_1();",5);
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/42IwSmPJPionvo5cXVOI?p=preview

Comment: maybe also add that surrounding `dom_obj.style.left=x; window.setTimeout("fun_1();",5);` with curly brackets means that those two lines of code will only be executed when `x>=300 or x<=-300`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not like coffeescript where the block are determined by indentation, in the control statements if there is no `{}` blocks only the first statement after the control statement is considered to be part of the control flow so your code without the `{}`(explicit block definition) will be same as

```
var x = 0,
    direction = 1;

function fun_1() {
    var dom_obj = document.getElementById("dir");
    x += direction;
    if (x >= 300 || x <= -300) {
        direction = -direction;
    }
    dom_obj.style.left = x;
    window.setTimeout("fun_1();", 5);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code means two different things depending on if you include or exclude curly braces.

If you use curly braces:

1. when the if condition is true, all the statements within the curly braces will execute
2. **when the if condition is false, none of the statements within the curly braces will execute**

If you do not use curly braces:

1. when the if condition is true, all the statements within the curly braces will execute
2. **when the if condition is false, only ONE statement immediately after the if statement will not execute. The remaining will execute.**

Answer (score 0):

Because You are putting Brace at the wrong place

It works with brace.

```
function fun_1() 
    {
        var dom_obj=document.getElementById("dir");
        x+=direction;
        if(x>=300 || x<=-300)
        {
            direction=-direction;
        }
        dom_obj.style.left=x;
        window.setTimeout("fun_1();",5);
    }
```

If statement does not care about indentation. Without braces it only affects the immediate 
statement i.e piece of code that appears in the next line.

So in this case,

```
if(x>=300 || x<=-300)
    direction=-direction;
    dom_obj.style.left=x;
    window.setTimeout("fun_1();",5);
```

`direction=-direction;` gets affected not

```
dom_obj.style.left=x;
window.setTimeout("fun_1();",5);
```

While you brace it, you are including

```
dom_obj.style.left=x;
window.setTimeout("fun_1();",5);
```

which was not included in the case where you do not use braces.